# Asserting a restriction on an associated value in an enum

Tags: swift, enums, preconditions

I have an enum like...

```
enum Analytics {
  case event(name: String)
  case other1
  case other2
}
```

But I need to make sure that the `name` value is no longer than 40 characters.

Is there a way to have some sort of precondition on the value put into the enum? I'm not sure where this would/should exist? If this were a struct I could put a `precondition` or something in the `init` but how would I do that for an enum?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible. Maybe create a `struct LimitedString { init(_ str: String) {... reduce size of fail } }, and use it `case event(name: LimitedString)`? Or if there were a way for a protocol to apply here... Just thinking, not sure it's feasable...

Comment: @Larme Thanks, yeah, I think the best way I can do this is to use `XCTFail` at the point of using it so that it is caught by tests and throws a runtime error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift, a restriction or refinement of a type can only be put in place using the type system.

```swift
enum Analytics {
  case event(name: String.LimitedTo20Count)
  case other1
  case other2
}

extension Collection {
  typealias LimitedTo20Count = ModuleName.LimitedTo20Count<Self>
}

struct LimitedTo20Count<Collection: Swift.Collection> {
  struct Error: Swift.Error { }
  
  init(wrappedValue: Collection) throws {
    guard wrappedValue.count <= 20 else {
      throw Error()
    }
    self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
  }

  let wrappedValue: Collection
}
```